# String rearrangement in R

Tags: regex, string, r, gsub

I am on the lookout for two R functions that would perform the following string rearrangements:
(1) place the parts following a ", " in a string at the start of a string, e.g.

```
name="2,6-Octadien-1-ol, 3,7-dimethyl-, (E)-"
```

should yield

```
"(E)-3,7-dimethyl-2,6-Octadien-1-ol"
```

(note that there could be any number of ", " in a string, or none at all, and that the parts after the ", " should be placed at the start of the string successively, starting from the end of the string. What would be the most efficient way of achieving this in R (without using loops etc)?

(2) place the parts between "<" and ">" at the start of a string and remove any ", ".
E.g.

```
name="Pyrazine <2-acetyl-, 3-ethyl->"
```

should yield

`"2-acetyl-3-ethyl-Pyrazine"`

(this is a simpler gsub problem, right?)
The part between the "<" and ">" could be in any place in the string though.
E.g.

`name="Cyclohexanol <4-tertbutyl-> acetate"` 
should yield

```
"4-tertbutyl-Cyclohexanol acetate"
```

Any thoughts would be welcome!

cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the first problem:

   ```
   name <- c("2,6-Octadien-1-ol, 3,7-dimethyl-, (E)-",
     "2,6-Octadien-1-ol,3,7-dimethyl-,(E)-")

   sapply(strsplit(name, "(?<!\\d), ?", perl = TRUE), function(x) 
     paste(rev(x), collapse = ""))
   # [1] "(E)-3,7-dimethyl-2,6-Octadien-1-ol" "(E)-3,7-dimethyl-2,6-Octadien-1-ol"
   ```
2. For the second problem:

   ```
   name <- c("Pyrazine <2-acetyl-, 3-ethyl->", 
             "Cyclohexanol <4-tertbutyl-> acetate")

   inside <- gsub(", ", "", sub("^.*<(.+)>.*$", "\\1", name))
   outside <- sub("^(.*) <.*>(.*)$" , "\\1\\2", name)
   paste0(inside, outside)
   # [1] "2-acetyl-3-ethyl-Pyrazine"        "4-tertbutyl-Cyclohexanol acetate"
   ```

Comment: @Tom Do you need the groups inside of the <> blocks to be reordered as in problem one?  i.e. should the result be 3-ethyl-2-acetyl-Pyrazine? Also, if there are mutiple <> block then the regex expression will give you some other grief, but could be dealt with using some loops I think.

Comment: Ha no there are not multiple <> blocks, and the expression inside them doesn't need to be reordered - so many thanks for that! This does the job perfectly - thanks millions!

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein: just a small additional problem - I have some cases as in problem one, but where the comma is not followed by a space. I.e., I would like e.g. name <- "2,6-Octadien-1-ol,3,7-dimethyl-,(E)-" to have rearranged to "(E)-3,7-dimethyl-2,6-Octadien-1-ol". Any thoughts how I should do that? In this case I think it should split at comma only when the preceding character is not a digit. How should I do this? Any thoughts?

Comment: @TomWenseleers I modified the regular expression for the first problem. Furthermore, I used `sapply` to apply the function to multiple strings at once.